# How to get the length of many arrays and get either the longest or shortest one by number of elements?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have several Arrays , I want to get for each of it the length,sort them (length),and assign each length to the appropriate Array:
I have to get identifying every array by his length,to get to get somthing like that :

```
if (i<smallest)
 { amount4[i]}

 if (i<next length+)
 {amount3[i]}

 if (i<next length++)
 {amount1[i]}

 if (i<next length+++)
 {amount2[i]}

 if (i<greatest)
 {amount5[i]}
```

Below my code :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    using System.Data;

    namespace ConsoleApplication9
    {
      class Program
      {
            static void Main(string[] args)
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string amount1 = "a1;a2;3";
            string amount2 = "b1;b2;b3;b4,b5";
            string amount3 = "c1;c2";
            string amount4 = "c1";
            string amount5 = "c1;c2;c3;c4;c5;c6";
            string[] splitamount1 = amount1.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
            string[] splitAmount2 = amount2.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
            string[] splitAmount3 = amount3.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
            string[] splitAmount4 = amount4.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
            string[] splitAmount5 = amount5.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
            int maxLength = Math.Max(Math.Max(Math.Max(Math.Max(splitamount1.Length, splitAmount2.Length), splitAmount3.Length), splitAmount4.Length), splitAmount5.Length);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You can make an array of arrays, then use linq to `OrderBy(x => x.Length)`

Comment: Tip, if you see yourself making many variables each with an ascending number suffix, you might want to look into a more dynamic way of holding information, like a collection/array/list.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the lengths of all of the arrays into a seperate array and then make sort the array using

```
Array.Sort(lengthArray);
```

Then you can check it like this:

```
if(someArray.Length == lengthArray[-1]) 
{
    //Do something when its the smallest array
}
if(someArray.Length == lengthArray[0]) 
{
    //Do something when its the largest array
}
```

Alternatively you can get the minimum and maximum value of the lengthArray using:

```
lengthArray.min();
lengthArray.max();
```

Comment: Why is this better than just making an array (or other dynamic collection) of arrays?